# Login from Android with Amplify and Login with Amazon

Tags: android, login-with-amazon, aws-amplify-sdk-android

I use Amplify on Android with the option Login with Amazon.

Unfortunately I get an:

```
AmplifyException {message=Sign in with web UI failed, cause=com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.cognitoauth.exceptions.AuthServiceException: invalid_request, recoverySuggestion=See attached exception for more details}
```

when I login with my Amazon account data. The sendet data is correct…
Can anyone help me out?

Thank you in advance!

Pingu

Comment: Please share some codes

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.

The problem was that only the admin could create new users. After I disabled this option it worked!